# using re.sub to find and replace all exact matches

Tags: python, django

The code below, aims to search hash signs in a string. If hash signed substrings ends in ([^\s#@$]*) it checks if the substring exists in database and if so it converts it to an anchor tag.

```
if not bool(BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser").find()):   
            if "#"  in content:
                title= re.findall(r"[#]([^\s#@$]*)(?=[\s#@$])", content)
                for i in title:
                    if i not in check_list:
                        check_list.append(i)
                        try:
                            title= Title.objects.get(title = i)
                            c = re.sub("[#]({})([^\s#@$]*)".format(i,),"<a class='title-link' href='/titles/{}'>{}</a>".format(i,i),c)
                        except:
                            continue
```

The problem occures when there is more then one hash signed substrings with the same value.

Say the string is:

```
"#title5 #title5xxx title5#title555"
```

The result is:

```
"<a class='title-link' href='/titles/title5'>title5</a> <a class='title-link' href='/titles/title5'>title5</a> title5<a class='title-link' href='/titles/title5'>title5</a>"
```

But I want it to be:

```
"<a class='title-link' href='/titles/title5'>title5</a> #title5xxx title5#title555"
```

Because I want re.sub function to replace only exact matches starting with "#" and ending in [s-#-@-$]
without replacing characters in which the string ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match only when next characters are in `\s#@$`, then why putting en negation on the set (i.e. having `[^xxx]`)? I think you miscopied the regexp pattern as you now have the full string following the # (which is in `i`) and you just want to stop the match from a character in your set: `\s#@$`

You should try the following:

```
c = re.sub("[#]({})([\s#@$]*)".format(i,),"<a class='title-link' href='/titles/{}'>{}</a>".format(i,i),c)
```

Comment: Yes that is correct, I think I got tunnelvisioned. Thank you very much.